# Conceptual Question about Interactions

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction, intuition

I have a question that are conceptual and statistical in nature. It might seem elemental but I am unable to find any clear answers online so I was hoping to find them here! They pertain to interactions.

Is it correct to assume roughly that when a predictor (that just reaches insignificance at -1SD of moderator p=.051 and significant at +1SD of moderator p < .001 is significant for roughly 85% of the individuals assuming a normal distribution? For me this would be a way to translate interaction terms into laymen terms.

PS: does this also apply to multilevel modeling?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. What do you mean by "significant for roughly %85 of individuals"? How can a predictor be significant for a percentage of individuals?

Comment: Hi Kjetil, thanks for taking the time to answer. I meant that the interaction shows that the effect of X is only not significant for individuals who score -1SD on the moderator. In other words, the effect is significant for everyone who scores higher for individuals who score higher than -1SD. Assuming a normal distribution of the moderator, i was wondering if this means the effect is significant for roughly 85% of the scores on the moderator?

Comment: Could you perhaps expand with an equation or syntax of the model you are fitting to make sure we understand correctly your scenario?